# Docker map port, host on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am relatively new in docker & EC2.

I have set up docker and I can run already in EC2.

```
docker-compose ps
```

[image]

I can also call like this.

```
curl -k https://localhost:9090
```

[image]

My EC2 public ip is this. (Changed to dummy one)

ec2-24-142-160-171.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

If I call to my EC2 public IP, I cannot access to that docker running on https://localhost:9090. How can I map so that I can call from my EC2 public IP?

Comment: Can you paste the output of this: `cat /etc/hosts` . Also make sure to allow 9090 from the security group of EC2 instance.

Comment: Follow https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/ if 9090 is not allowed in your ec2 instance.